# Change CSS of a table cell if it has text that's same as a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an table full of cells. And there is variable. Let's say the variable is dd = the current day and the table contains days from the current month. For instance, for July, the table cells are populated by numbers 1 to 30.
I want to be able to find the cell with the variable, and change the css of the cell with the variable. Say, if the variable is 10, on document.ready, all the cells should be searched for "10" and if there is a match, the css properties of that specific cell has to be changed.
Here's something I've tried:

```
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();

(".tcell").each(function (){
   var curdate = $(this).find(dd).html();
   var curd = $(this).find(dd).attr('id');
});

if (curdate = dd){
   alert(curdate);
   $(curd).css('color','red');
}
```

Why doesn't this work? It just alerts the date but doesn't do anything to the cell which has the text that is same as the variable.

PS: It's not about dates or days, but any table and/or variables.
Thank you.

Comment: You are missing the dollar sign($) at beginning of third row.
$(".tcell").each(function (){
But there is more.  Can you post a snippet of your table html?

Comment: [`find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) takes a selector or an element. `dd` is a number. So unless you have an element named like `<10></10>` in your HTML, that's not going to match anything.  Please read [the documentation on selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) and see if you can figure out the correct one to use.

Comment: Please, learn about the differences between `=`, `==` and `===` in JavaScript. In your specific case: `if (curdate = dd){` is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();

$(".tcell").each(function (index, el){
   var curdate = parseInt($(el).html());

   if (curdate == dd){
      alert(curdate);
      $(el).css('color','red');
   }
});
```

If it is working, the error was about scope. 
Indeed, `curdate` is not defined outside the callback of the each function. Moreover, if `curdate` was global, the test would have been executed only for the last value and not for each iteration as it is outside of the callback function.

You can read more about scopes here : https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp

Answer (score -2):

Here's the code:

```js
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
document.querySelectorAll(".cell").forEach(function(cell) {
  cell.classList.remove("active");
  if (parseInt(cell.innerText) === parseInt(dd)) {
    cell.classList.add("active");
  }
});
```

```css
.cell {
  padding: 10px;
  background: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
}

.cell.active {
  background: #CC0000;
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="cell">01</td>
      <td class="cell">02</td>
      <td class="cell">03</td>
      <td class="cell">04</td>
      <td class="cell">05</td>
      <td class="cell">06</td>
      <td class="cell">07</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="cell">08</td>
      <td class="cell">09</td>
      <td class="cell">10</td>
      <td class="cell">11</td>
      <td class="cell">12</td>
      <td class="cell">13</td>
      <td class="cell">14</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="cell">15</td>
      <td class="cell">16</td>
      <td class="cell">17</td>
      <td class="cell">18</td>
      <td class="cell">19</td>
      <td class="cell">20</td>
      <td class="cell">21</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="cell">22</td>
      <td class="cell">23</td>
      <td class="cell">24</td>
      <td class="cell">25</td>
      <td class="cell">26</td>
      <td class="cell">27</td>
      <td class="cell">28</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="cell">29</td>
      <td class="cell">30</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

You can check on [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rENBMp).

Comment: Please read [answer] to find out what makes a good answer. A link to a different website does not make a good answer.